# Passing a comparison function and value as parameters into Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

This is a follow-up on question on [Passing a comparison function as a parameter into Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893229/passing-a-comparison-function-as-a-parameter-into-entity-framework).

I would like to pass a comparison function and a value into a search function that queries Entity Framework. The comparison function has to operate on different properties depending on the value. E.g., my data is

```
class DataItem
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }
  public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and I need a context method

```
public List<DataItem> SearchValue(Func<string, string, bool> op, string value)
{
  if (value.Length < 10)
    return DataItem.Where(di => di.Active && op(di.Prop1, value)).ToList();
  else
    return DataItem.Where(di => di.Active && op(di.Prop2, value)).ToList();
}
```

that I can then call like

```
List<DataItem> list = context.SearchValue((s1, s2) => s1 == s2, "A");
```

where I also need different comparison functions (all canonical).

Program compiles alright, but on running I get a "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." error.

Loading the DataItems into memory is not an option since I'll have around a billion of them. That's why I'm looking for a server-side solution. All the operations I'm using are canonical, so they can be translated into SQL queries. My question is just: how can I pass them as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This issue means that your LINQ query cannot be converted to a proper SQL query for backend execution.All LINQ to SQL or Entity framework queries get converted to SQL which is run on the backend and if they have some operation which could not be translated to SQL this error can come.

I think you should first bring your data in memory using .ToList() or .AsEnumerable() and then use 'Op' operation on that.That should solve the problem

Comment: Yes, I understand the error message. Unfortunately loading the values into memory is not an option - see updated question...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do it with LinqToEntities. You have to create sql query manually or call Database function...